# I want to make headers in a listview and add items under each listview in a UWP app. How should I do this?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xaml, uwp

I am making an app that tracks what a person eats.  I want to have a listview that tracks all the food eaten during the day and lists it under what meal (breakfast, lunch, dinner, and snack) that the user ate it during.

I understand how to add the item to the list.  The only problem is I don't know how to add headers like the ones shown in the XAML Gallery, and I don't know how to add items under a specific header.  I've had some difficulty finding tutorials that explain how to do this and would like some input as to where I should look.

I've looked at these tutorials ([tutorial 1](https://damienaicheh.github.io/uwp/2018/07/23/how-to-display-a-grouped-list-in-uwp-en.html), [tutorial 2](https://csharp.christiannagel.com/2016/08/29/uwpgrouping/)) but they are somewhat confusing and I'm honestly not sure if what they show is what I'm trying to do.

What is the name of what I'm trying to do, and how should I go about it? Any tutorials for what it is I'm trying to accomplish would be very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

From your description, It seems you want to implement a grouping list. The recommended way is to use CollectionViewSource, which is very detailed in the tutorials you showed. You can create a class that includes time (breakfast...), food name, etc., then group them by time. For more information about collectionViewSource, you can refer to this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.UI.Xaml.Data.CollectionViewSource). If you are still confused, can you describe in more detail where is the problem?